# Get more than one elements from array in QGIS expressions using square brackets

Tags: qgis, expression, array

Using QGIS expressions, if you have an array, you can get the n-th element by simply adding a number (n) in square brackets (starting with 0 for the first element). Like this, `array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)[2]` returns `3` (element no. 2/third element).

Is there a way to retrieve more than one element in this way with QGIS expressions?

What I tried, based on similar options in R, but doesn't work here:

`array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)[2,3]` -- to retrieve elements 2 and 3
`array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)[array(2,5)]` -- to retrieve elements 2, 3 and 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess no. At least in Python they are called [**index brackets**](https://py.processing.org/reference/indexbrackets.html) and are not meant to contain several indizes. Don't know about other languages like R or C. But you can build a custom function:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
# arr is an array-input you want to return several values from by their index
# idxarr is an array-input containing the indizes you want to return from arr
def array_get_several(arr, idxarr, feature, parent):
    elements = [arr[i] for i in idxarr]
    return elements
```

and use it as `array_get_several(array(1,2,3,4,5,6),array(1,2))` which for example returns `[2,3]`. Note that it returns the values ordered, so e.g. `array_get_several(array(1,2,3,4,5,6),array(2,1))` does return `[3,2]`.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-slice

Comment: @geozelot good point, but will only work for a range. Not e.g. to return **only** index `1` and `4`, but **not** `2` and `3`. However, worth posting as answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

Addendum to @MrXsquared's answer. You can also define a range of indexes.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def array_get_range(arr, start, end, feature, parent):
    return arr[start:end] # exclusive end
```

`array_get_range( array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 2, 6 )` returns `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-slice

Comment: @geozelot QGIS already has a function for the second approach. Trying to solve directly in PyQGIS instead of searching if there is a solution in Expression is my bad habit. :DD

Comment: Oh that's not the worst habit ,) No need to reinvent the wheel, though.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @MrXsquared is indeed an elegant way to do that, lacking the simple way with just square brackets.

With just native functions, a workaround would be:

```
array_foreach (
    array(0,3),
    array_get (array(1,2,3,4,5,6), @element)
)
```

returns: `[ 1, 4 ]` (position 0 and 3, defined in line 2).

Comment: ...and the proper way would be to use `array_slice`. In lower level languages you are referring to the extraction of consecutive array element as *slicing the (underlying) array*, usually implemented additionally for convenience using *bracket slice notation* `[<start>:<end>]`.